# Updating Associative Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

It may just be that I've checked out already for the weekend, but having a bit of trouble updating an associative array based on a certain value. For example, here is what I have so far:

```
$slideshow_vars = array(
        'js_animation'          => $slideshow_options['js_animation'],
        'js_slide_direction'    => $slideshow_options['js_slide_direction'],
        'js_slideshow'          => $slideshow_options['js_slideshow'],
        'js_slideshow_speed'    => $slideshow_options['js_slideshow_speed'],
        'js_animation_duration' => $slideshow_options['js_animation_duration'],
        'js_direction_nav'      => $slideshow_options['js_direction_nav'],
        'js_control_nav'        => $slideshow_options['js_control_nav'],
        'js_keyboard_nav'       => $slideshow_options['js_keyboard_nav'],
        'js_mousewheel'         => $slideshow_options['js_mousewheel'],
        'js_prev_text'          => $slideshow_options['js_prev_text'],
        'js_next_text'          => $slideshow_options['js_next_text'],
        'js_pause_play'         => $slideshow_options['js_pause_play'],
        'js_pause_text'         => $slideshow_options['js_pause_text'],
        'js_play_text'          => $slideshow_options['js_play_text'],
        'js_randomize'          => $slideshow_options['js_randomize'],
        'js_slide_start'        => $slideshow_options['js_slide_start'],
        'js_animation_loop'     => $slideshow_options['js_animation_loop'],
        'js_pause_on_action'    => $slideshow_options['js_pause_on_action'],
        'js_pause_on_hover'     => $slideshow_options['js_pause_on_hover'],
        'js_controls_container' => $slideshow_options['js_controls_container'],
        'js_manual_controls'    => $slideshow_options['js_manual_controls'],
        'js_start_function'     => $slideshow_options['js_start_function'],
        'js_before_function'    => $slideshow_options['js_before_function'],
        'js_after_function'     => $slideshow_options['js_after_function'],
        'js_end_function'       => $slideshow_options['js_end_function']
    );
foreach ($slideshow_vars as $key => $value) {
    if($value == NULL) {
        $value = "false";
    }
}
print_r($slideshow_vars);
```

In a number of the values in the array, they are outputting `NULL` -- well, I need to change those to a string of `false` (this data is being localized and then sent to a JS file which expects false). When I perform the above `print_r()` it hasn't actually updated anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because foreach normally passes array fields by value.
What you need to do is this:

```
foreach ($slideshow_vars as $key => &$value) {
    if($value == NULL) {
        $value = "false";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Just so it's clear to the OP how this differs from his code I'd say in your answer that you added the `&` in front of `$value` and even link to the manual page on PHP references: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: Now there's a sentence I forgot to include.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update arrays like this by using the canonical path:

```
$slideshow_vars[$key] = 'false';
```

Or what [cyper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371707/cypher) mentioned by using `... as $key => &$value` to pass the inner loop the reference of `$value` instead of just its value.

Answer (score 1):

Each loop, `$value` is set to the value. By updating the value of `$value`, you're just changing it in the local scope, and not setting the value inside that array. For that, you want to reference the field and update it, as such:

```
foreach ($slideshow_vars as $key => $value) {
    if($value == NULL) {
        $slideshow_vars[$key] = "false";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all of the keys are the same and you want to save yourself a lot of code, you could try experimenting with this:

```
$slideshow_vars = array_merge( // Merge two arrays:
    // Create an array of the same keys, but all with values of "false"
    array_combine( 
        array_keys( $slideshow_options), 
        array_fill( 0, count( $slideshow_options), "false")
    ), 
    // Remove values that equal false (may need to specify a more precise callback here)
    array_filter( $slideshow_options)
);
```

This should give you the `$slideshow_vars` variable you're looking for.

Comment: @Zach - You can try this solution if you want to be able to handle changing array keys.